# When I check for update in macOS, are the software from other sources checked for updates as well?

Tags: macos, software-update

So far as my experience goes, some software are available directly from  Mac App Store, others are installed from other source e.g. [gimp for Mac](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/Mac.html).

When I check for updates in Mac, does it check for updates for the second category as well?

If the answer is no, how do I know whether a new version for gimp has been released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac App Store will only check for updates for system applications or those installed from the Mac App Store.

Though I have not used Gimp in particular, most apps distributed outside of the Mac App Store will have an option in the menu bar under either the *app name* or `help` menus. That option will usually be titled something along the lines of `Check for Updates`.

You can download the latest version of Gimp here: [Gimp - Downloads](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/).

[image]

Comment: So, to summarize, Mac App Store will only check for its own applications, and for other applications, each one must be checked *individually*. This is very much different from Ubuntu (and similar ones) where you add repositories for all the software except a few and a simple command like `sudo apt-get update` will suffice to check for updates.

Comment: @Masroor To my understanding that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the info in the documentation for Support Essentials cert exam I'm reading:

> macOS Software Update attempts to update this software:
>
> - Currently installed Apple-source software
> - macOS bundled software
> - Software you bought from the App Store